# Posting from php to Flask

Tags: php, python, curl, flask

[image]

I have a php app which posts variable info to a flask app (which does some calculations and returns a result ). I'm running both locally on win7

When I test the url "127.0.0.1:5000/index" using a post with postman, I get a 200 status code (screenshot). However when the php app posts to the flask app I get:

```
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

I'm using CURL , and the verbose output is:

```
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 5000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> POST /index/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 338
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------d5cb02e2edea
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 233
< Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.5
```

My php code looks like:

```
   $data= array('a'=>$a, 'token'=>$token);
   $url="http://127.0.0.1:5000/index/";
   $output = $this->my_model->get_data($url, $data);

public function get_data($url,$postFieldArray=FALSE) {

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
if ($postFieldArray!= FALSE) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFieldArray); //for django
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
.......

return $result;
}
```

Simplified Flask app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/index',methods=['POST'])
def index():

    token = request.form['token']
    a = request.form['a']
    ......
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My psychic debugging powers say that you should remove the trailing slash from `$url` :-)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. would you like to enter it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing slash in the `$url` variable in the PHP code. That won't work, because you don't have a trailing slash in your Flask code. Look [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#variable-rules) for more info, under the section "Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior"